# Moshi adapter to skip bad objects in the List<T>

Tags: android, json, kotlin, adapter, moshi

I use Moshi and I need to solve my problem with a buggy backend. Sometimes, when I request a list of objects, some of them don't contain mandatory fields. Of course, I can catch and process `JsonDataException`, but I want to skip these objects. How can I do it with Moshi?

**Update**

I have a couple of models for my task

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class User(
        val name: String,
        val age: Int?
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class UserList(val list: List<User>)
```

and buggy JSON

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "age": 18
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane",
      "age": 21
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see, the second object has no mandatory `name` field and I want to skip it via Moshi adapter.

Comment: Post the code on how you're setting up your Moshi adapter.

Comment: @SharpMobileCode I have no code for the adapter. I just want to write it =) But I can show code with models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I've found the answer

```
class SkipBadListObjectsAdapterFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
    override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        return if (annotations.isEmpty() && Types.getRawType(type) == List::class.java) {
            val elementType = Types.collectionElementType(type, List::class.java)
            val elementAdapter = moshi.adapter<Any>(elementType)

            SkipBadListObjectsAdapter(elementAdapter)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    private class SkipBadListObjectsAdapter<T : Any>(private val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<T>) :
        JsonAdapter<List<T>>() {
        override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): List<T>? {
            val goodObjectsList = mutableListOf<T>()

            reader.beginArray()

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    elementAdapter.fromJson(reader)?.let(goodObjectsList::add)
                } catch (e: JsonDataException) {
                    // Skip bad element ;)
                }
            }

            reader.endArray()

            return goodObjectsList

        }

        override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: List<T>?) {
            throw UnsupportedOperationException("SkipBadListObjectsAdapter is only used to deserialize objects")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you "guys from the  other topics" =)

Comment: Consider using JsonReader.peekJson() to get a copy of the current JsonReader that doesn't consume. You can use skip() to skip the full value even if a nested object is malformed.

Comment: I am running into an issue with how this jives with Kotlin generics it would appear.  The exception I keep getting is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No JsonAdapter for E (with no annotations)`.  If anyone has a workaround it would be much appreciated! Also, I feel like Moshi should offer this functionality out of the box as an annotation or something. Its pretty common in a lot of other parsers.

Answer (score 5):

There's a gotcha in the solution that only catches and ignores after failure. If your element adapter stopped reading after an error, the reader might be in the middle of reading a nested object, for example, and then the next hasNext call will be called in the wrong place.

As Jesse mentioned, you can peek and skip the entire value.

```
class SkipBadElementsListAdapter(private val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any?>) :
    JsonAdapter<List<Any?>>() {
  object Factory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
    override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
      if (annotations.isNotEmpty() || Types.getRawType(type) != List::class.java) {
        return null
      }
      val elementType = Types.collectionElementType(type, List::class.java)
      val elementAdapter = moshi.adapter<Any?>(elementType)
      return SkipBadElementsListAdapter(elementAdapter)
    }
  }

  override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): List<Any?>? {
    val result = mutableListOf<Any?>()
    reader.beginArray()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      try {
        val peeked = reader.peekJson()
        result += elementAdapter.fromJson(peeked)
      } catch (ignored: JsonDataException) {
      }
      reader.skipValue()
    }
    reader.endArray()
    return result

  }

  override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: List<Any?>?) {
    if (value == null) {
      throw NullPointerException("value was null! Wrap in .nullSafe() to write nullable values.")
    }
    writer.beginArray()
    for (i in value.indices) {
      elementAdapter.toJson(writer, value[i])
    }
    writer.endArray()
  }
}
```

Comment: This implementation crashes with `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` when the create is called.
`com.squareup.moshi.adapters.PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.create(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.java:216)`

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working solution here:

> https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1288

Happy fixing :)