# Moshi adapter to ignore bad elements from a polymorphic list

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have a polymorphic list of contents sent by the backend.
I use PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory to parse it to Kotlin objects. It all works fine.
When the backend sends an element with an unknown type there is no problem I apply a default value.

The issue comes when the backend sends a wrong element (required attribute missing) with a recognized type. In this case, moshi stops and throws a JsonDataException. I would like to ignore these elements.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145519/moshi-adapter-to-skip-bad-objects-in-the-listt) thread but it concerns a list of just one type.

The only solution I could find so far is making EVERY field on the Kotlin data classes optional and filter out later. But it's not ideal.

#### Example

Let's assume I have this :

```
enum class Type {
   FISH,
   BIRD
}

sealed class Animal(val type: Type) {
   data class Fish(
     val requiredField : String,
   ): Animal(Type.FISH)
   data class Bird(
     val requiredField : String,
   ): Animal(Type.BIRD)
}
```

And I receive a list of Animal.

So I'll have :

```
PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Animal::class.java, "type")
            .withSubtype(Fish::class.java, Type.FISH)
            .withSubtype(Bird::class.java, Type.BIRD)
            .withSubtype(Input::class.java, ActionType.input.name))
            .withDefaultValue(UnknownEntity())
```

This will handle this json perfectly :

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "type": "FISH",
      "requiredField": "blablabla",
    },
    {
      "type": "ANIMAL",
      "requiredField": "blablabla"
    },
    {
       "type": "Nothing",
    }
  ]
}
```

But not this one because fish required field is missing are missing :

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "type": "FISH",
    },
    {
      "type": "ANIMAL",
      "requiredField": "blablabla"
    },
  ]
}
```

Do you have a solution for this ? Seems like a pretty normal usecase

Comment: Bear in mind that the provided code is just an example that I wrote directly on stack overflow editor so there might be errors. But it should still be a good example for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my [`SkipBadElementsListAdapter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190660/1696171) from your linked thread, and it seems to do what you want. Correct me if I misunderstood (preferably with a demonstrating test case).

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val animalJsonAdapterFactory = PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Animal::class.java, "type")
    .withSubtype(Animal.Fish::class.java, Type.FISH.name)
    .withSubtype(Animal.Bird::class.java, Type.BIRD.name)
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(SkipBadElementsListAdapter.Factory)
    .add(animalJsonAdapterFactory)
    .build()
  val animalsJsonAdapter =
    moshi.adapter<List<Animal>>(Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Animal::class.java))
  println(animalsJsonAdapter.fromJson(encoded))
}

enum class Type {
  FISH,
  BIRD
}

sealed class Animal(val type: Type) {
  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
  data class Fish(
    val requiredField: String,
  ) : Animal(Type.FISH)

  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
  data class Bird(
    val requiredField: String,
  ) : Animal(Type.BIRD)
}

val encoded = """
  [
    {
      "type": "FISH",
      "requiredField": "blablabla"
    },
    {
      "type": "BIRD",
      "requiredField": "blablabla"
    },
    {
      "type": "BIRD"
    }
  ]
""".trimIndent()
```

This prints `[Fish(requiredField=blablabla), Bird(requiredField=blablabla)]`. It ignores the bad element, as it seems you want it to do.

Comment: No no, you are completely right. As it turns out what I was missing was its usage. Thought I had to initialize it myself, passing it a type (which is exactly what I didn't want to do). 
But no, I can just pass a Factory and Moshi does its magic.
Thanks for answering and for writing that adapter 

Comment: Great, glad the usage example helped